# Is it a good idea to use a file to log user access to a ASP.Net 4 site? If not why not?

Tags: asp.net, iis, logging

I have an app that requires me to track a user as they interact with it. Things that I need to log include; User login, User logout, Page views with some details about what the user did to get where they are.

It is a multi user site and could have as many as 50 concurrent users on it. I have it in my head that logging this stuff to a file could cause threading issues in IIS during heavy usage.

I am looking for some good reasons I should go though the effort of using a DB or other method of logging. Keep in mind that I don't currently have any use for a DB in my app. So I am not keen on adding one to the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest consideration is how you intend to consume this log data. If all you want to do is open the log file and see what people are doing, in the order that they are doing it, then a file will work just fine. Or if you need the data purely for audit purposes, so in the rare case that there's an issue you can go back through all your log files and parse them to find some specific useful tidbit, a simple file will probably work well enough. Concurrency issues are handled well by most modern logging frameworks.

On the other hand, if you want to be able to effectively query the data, a database table will give you a lot more power. For example, you can see just the actions taken by a given user during a given time period, if you have captured the time and active user as separate fields in the database table. Or you could identify common issues by grouping the ERROR-level messages by the top line of their stacktrace, and order them by the total Count per line of code that they occurred on.

Either way, I'd recommend using a well-known logging framework like Log4Net or NLog: they address most of the issues that you'd run into, and they make it easy, if you change your mind in the future, to change what gets logged and where it gets logged to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a fine idea.  Don't build your own framework, though.  There are already a gamut of great solutions, some lightweight like `Log4Net`, some more "enterprisey" like `EnterpriseLoggingLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

As for implementation:

Well, you would need either an HttpModule, or use a Dependency Injection container that runs in one (like Ninject.Web)

Then you can just have a worker thread in the module collect log data with a logging framework (like log4net)  and write to a file.